# Additional Include Directories Difficulties

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, ftgl

I'm trying to include the FTGL library into my graphics project, but I keep getting c1083 error whenever I try to include the main header file:

```
#include <include/FTGL/ftgl.h>
```

I have added the path $(Project1)include\FTGL to "Additional Include Directories" and VC++ Include Directories to no avail. Project1 is the main solution folder and "include" is the folder where the headers for glew and whatnot are.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you forget the backslash in  $(Project1)include\FTGL?

Comment: And try `#include <ftgl.h>` if the additional include dir is called ` $(Project1)\include\FTGL`.
Or try $(Project1)\include as the dir and use `#include <FTGL/ftgl.h>`.

Comment: As the question stands, you are trying to use `$(Project1)include\FTGL\include\FTGL\ftgl.h`

Comment: Additionally, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules here are very simple. Say you have a file on your hard drive:

```
C:\abc\def\include\FTGL\ftgl.h
```

Then you need to add an include path `C:\abc\def` to your project and the include statement:

```
#include <include/FTGL/ftgl.h>
```

This was tested 1000 times. Works fine! Once you will make this working, start experimenting with `$(Project1)` and other VS variables.